# libopenblas for travis-ci: mixing blas,lapack,atlas,openblas

Tags: linux, openblas

I have the travis-ci [testing script](https://github.com/miroi/autocmake/blob/236c963b673a9517edad00770b6e09fe7a280868/.travis.yml) where one have to install system blas+lapack, atlas and openblas:

libblas-dev, liblapack-dev, libatlas-base-dev, libopenblas-base , libopenblas-dev

All mentioned packages are not working at once; bringing in the libopenblas packages are messing things up for virtual linux servers of travis-ci.

Has someone similar experience with Linux and these packges ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I sorted it out with travis-ci: libblas-dev and libopenblas-dev can be together. The libopenblas package can not "withstand" liblapack, libatlas packages.